# Tracy gets shot, no effect

Tags: firefly

In the Firefly episode *[The Message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_%28Firefly%29)*, we see that [Tracey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_characters#Tracey_Smith) comes aboard and gets shot by [Zoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_characters#Zoe_Washburne) at close range with a shotgun on the bridge. But he doesn't flinch or seems to be affected by the bullet at all. But later, when [Malcolm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_characters#Malcolm_Reynolds) shoots him with a pistol he falls to the ground.

Why was there no reaction to the shot Zoe fired at Tracey?

Comment: Just conjecture, but maybe possibly he was running off of adrenaline far beyond what he realistically could sustain, and the shock of being shot by Mal is what finally caused it all to drop out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

One is simply that the shotgun pellets simply didn't hit anything critical (i.e. Tracey got really, really lucky).

A more likely (in my opinion) explanation is that the lab-grown organs Tracey was smuggling allowed him to shrug off an unusual portion of the pain and shock of getting shot.

The organs were described as being experimental, and seemed to work differently than normal organs:

> SIMON
>   Captain, I don't mean
>   to... We may have a medical
>   emergency here...
>
> They all look at him; he's looking at the monitor.
>
> SIMON (cont'd)
>   This man appears to be in
>   cardiac arrest...
>
> MAL
>   What? Tracey, you having a heart attack?
>   (to Simon)
>   Don't look like he's having a heart attack...
>
> TRACEY
>   (laughs)
>   Don't pay any attention to your
>   machines, doc. They'll fib to ya.
>   Heart's just fine. Better'n fine.
>   Just runs a little hotter'n usual, that's all.
>
> SIMON
>   (off, monitors)
>   My god... it's not just the heart
>   muscle... it's everything...

... and then ...

> ZOE
>   You're smuggling human organs?
>
> TRACEY
>   They're grown in a lab.
>   The only way they can move them is in a
>   person. Not sure why.
>
> SIMON
>   Because the technology's not ready.
>   The blastomeres are unapproved.
>   Likely unstable. You're not just a
>   carrier -- you're an incubator.

Comment: Yea.. but then why does Mal's shot have an effect on Tracy?

Comment: He's not bulletproof.  He's just more resistant to damage than normal.  The first shot hurt him worse than he let on, but Mal's shot penetrated deeper and did more immediate damage.

Comment: Another possibility is that the pain-inducing nerves to said organs are no longer attached... he may not FEEL the pain, literally, depending on where exactly the pellets penetrated. The organs were only supposed to be in him a short period, after which his originals would be put back in. Based on that, there may have been no point in hooking everything back up... just enough to pass any scans.

Comment: Or, since Zoe new the plan and did not want to kill Tracy she just winged him.  Being the veteran soldier and crack shot that she is it was to prevent him from doing something stupid, which he went and did anyway.

Comment: Then, once he does something stupid, Mal had to put him down before someone got hurt.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mistaken.

As far as I can remember, Tracey arrives on *[Serenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_%28Firefly_vessel%29)* in a cargo box that was parceled to captain Malcolm Reynolds. When they opened the box, Tracy's body was in it. They assumed that he was dead, and they took him in.

When they opened the box again on the ship they found the recorded "message" and decided to take him to his folks.

While on their way, they were intercepted by Alliance law officer, Lieutenant Womack. That is when Mal asks Simon to perform the autopsy. When Simons starts the autopsy he performs a cut on Tracey's chest, the shock/pain of which brings Tracy out of his "death", that is, the induced death state.

So see, no shooting by Zoe.

**Update:**

My mistake! I watched the part again. Zoe did shoot Tracey. Tracey does get wounded. He is wounded, but he does not slow down. He takes [Kaylee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_characters#Kaylee_Frye) hostage, and you can see that he is hurt from the way he is struggling to walk and talk.

The second shot by Mal does the job and Tracey is knocked out.

My apologies for the wrong answer first time.